# Looping error with lists: for function not works inside purrr::map2 in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, nested, purrr

I built a function to use it inside the `purrr::map2` function and run it in two lists. When I run the function steps separately it works ok. But apparently in `map2` it runs the first time (for the first elements of list `.x[[1]] .y[[1]]`) and then in the second round throws this error in the `for` function:

[image]

How can I find out why it's not working?

PS: It's hard to put an example of the data here because they are lists with very specific characteristics for this function. I'm sorrry.

Follow the function:

```
df <- list()

build_HUW_raster <- function(.x, .y) {
  list.time <- .x %>%
    split(.$id) %>%
    purrr::map(~list(t=as.matrix(.x$date),
                     xy=unname(as.matrix(.x[,c(22,23)])))
    )
 
  for(i in 1:50){
    cat(i," ")
    path=list.time[[i]]
    ctmc=ctmcmove::path2ctmc(path$xy,path$t,r,method="LinearInterp")
    df[[i]] <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, ctmc))
  }
 
  df <-  df %>% purrr::map(~ group_by(., ec) %>%
                             summarise(rt = mean(rt)) %>%
                             arrange(desc(rt))
  )
 
  stacktime <- df %>% purrr::map(~ rename(., cell = ec)) %>%
    map(~dplyr::left_join(cargo.grid, ., by="cell", copy=T)) %>%
    map(~raster::rasterize(., r, field="rt", na.rm=F, background=0)) %>%
    raster::stack()
 
  stackprop <- .y %>%
    split(.$id) %>%
    purrr::map(~ raster::rasterize(., y = r,
                                   field=.$proportion,
                                   fun=function(x, ...)median(x))) %>%
                 raster::stack()
   
  stack_huw <- raster::overlay(raster::calc(stacktime, fun=function(x)
      ifelse(is.na(x), NA, x/sum(x, na.rm=T))), stackprop, fun=function(x,y)x*y
      )
 
      raster_mean <- raster::stackApply(stack_huw,
      indices = rep(1,raster::nlayers(stack_huw)),
      fun = "mean",
      na.rm = F
  )
}

result.list <- purrr::map2 (.x=list1, .y=list2, fun=build_HUW_raster)
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `list1[1]` and `list2[1]`.  Not clear where the `map2` is used.  The reason is that `[` returns a `list` where as `[[` extracts the elemetns inside the list and depending on the structure of the elements, it may get individually looped i.e. if it is a data.frame inside, the columns are the units, so it loops over the columns.

Comment: The purrr::map2 function is used later with the function that is built inside. Yes, there is a problem in the loop only, because the for function works if used individually. I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: If the `map2` is used on the first element of the list, the solution should work with `[`

Comment: Forgive ignorance. Where? Inside ```for``` or ```map2```?

Comment: i.e. in your code `purrr::map2 (.x=list1[1], .y=list2[1], fun=build_HUW_raster)` (assuming your question is about passing the first list element into map2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is based on the element looped. `[[` extracts the list element and depending on the class of the element, `map` loops over either individual elements if it is a vector/matrix or the columns in case of data.frame as these are units.  By using `[`, it extracts the element as a list

```
list(1, 2, 3)[1]
[[1]]
[1] 1
```

vs

```
list(1, 2, 3)[[1]]
[1] 1
```

When we loop over `map` and apply some functions that require a specific structure i.e. `colSums` require a matrix/data.frame ie. with dim attributes, it fails if we use `[[`

```
> map(replicate(2,  data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10), simplify = FALSE)[[1]], colSums)
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
> map(replicate(2,  data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10), simplify = FALSE)[1], colSums)
[[1]]
col1 col2 
  15   40
```

---

Here, we may change the code to

```
purrr::map2(.x=list1[1], .y=list2[1], fun=build_HUW_raster)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The lists that I will insert in ```map2``` have 30 elements. If I write purrr::map2(list1[1], list2[1], fun) isn't it running only once? I have little expertise in programming.

Comment: @CarolinePortal  yes.  it runs only the first element.  if you need to run the whole list, your initial code works, right? i..e `map2(.x=list1, .y=list2, fun=build_HUW_raster)`.  also, if you are doing this inside a for loop why not just use `result_out <- vector('list', length(list1)); for(i in seq_along(list1)) result_out[[i]] <- build_HUW_raster(list1[[i]], list2[[i]])`

Comment: Not, it's on the contrary, I misspoke. I don't speak english flow. The ```ctmcmove::path2ctmc``` function is from a specific package that shows in the console when it is running, so I can see that it ran for the first time and in the second round it gives the error. I learned to loop with ```purrr::map``` so I use this format, ```for``` function used inside code was copied from ```ctmc``` package document . I will try as you mentioned now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CarolinePortal  You either use `for` loop or `map/map2`,  Maybe you were trying to use `map2` within a for loop which is kind of roundabout way.  THe main reason for using map/lapply/Map when compared to `for` loop is it is easier to get the output in a list, rather than preallocating an output list for storing the output

Comment: Solved. With ```for()``` also gave the same error, a ```drop=T``` was missing inside the ```split``` function, that was generating empty layers. I am very grateful for the help, the discussions here always bring me insights that generate the solution I need. Best

Comment: @CarolinePortal Yes, `split` does that.  Perhaps use `group_split` from `dplyr` (though it doesn't return a named list)